# Two pixels added to absolute position of elements added via javascript in chrome only

Tags: google-chrome, input, textbox, alignment, pixel

Here's my first question on stackoverflow. I've used you guys to answer many many questions in the past, but this time, I wan't able to find what I was looking for, so any help would be appreciated!

I have a simple website I was playing with to brush up on css, javascript, jQuery, and html. I have an issue where I want to add an input textbox via javascript directly below the lowest existing textbox. It seems fairly simple, and it works properly in ie9 and firefox, but in chrome, each new textbox is pushed over to the right by 2 pixels.

Here is the html and javascript code:

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header> <h3>Header to the 3rd degree!</h3></header>
        <section class="textboxes">

            <input type="textbox"  class="duplicate" />

        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
$(function(){$('.duplicate').attr('onclick', 'createInputBox()');   });
function createInputBox(){

    var inputs = $('.duplicate');
    var lastInput = inputs[inputs.length - 1];

    var position = getAbsolutePosition(lastInput);
    var x = position[0];
    var y = position[1] + 25;
    $('.textboxes').append(inputTextBoxOpenTag + "style=\"position:absolute; left:" + x + "px; top:" + y + "px;\">" + inputTextBoxCloseTag );   
}

function getAbsolutePosition(object){

    var curleft = curtop = 0;

    if(object.offsetParent){

        do{
            curleft += object.offsetLeft;
            curtop += object.offsetTop;
        } while(object = object.offsetParent);

        return [curleft, curtop];
    }
}

var inputTextBoxOpenTag = "<input type=\"textbox\" class=\"duplicate\" onclick=\"createInputBox()\"  "
var inputTextBoxCloseTag="</input>"
```

So the basic idea is every time you click in a text box, a new one is added below the last textbox.

The new textbox position is set using the current position of the last textbox. After debugging in chrome, I could see that the horizontal position, x, was being set to the actual value I wanted. However, when the function was called again, it claimed that the actual position was 2 pixels greater than what it had set it to in the last function call.

Though this page obviously isn't meant to be used for anything important, I feel knowing what is causing this issue may give me more information on why chrome is displaying some textboxes on another site I'm working on out of line, while firefox and ie9 display them just fine.

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Is this the complete code, or is there CSS styles we should know about? I haven't been able to reproduce the behavior in chrome, based on the code you've provided so far. [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/NKPB8/).

Comment: No, this is all there is, but given that info, I may want to try testing on a different machine. Thanks!

Comment: [Here's a simplified version of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/WNV6G/) btw. You don't have to access index to find the last element, you can use the `:last` pseudo-selector. You don't have to have the HTML in string variables, you can create a copy with `clone()`. You don't have to roll your own function to find out an elements position relative to its offset parent, you can use `offset()` (see the documentation for differences between that and `position()`).

Comment: ... And you don't have to set the `onclick` attribute to a string version of a function call. Actually, for compatibility, you shouldn't. Prefer `$('.duplicate').click(function() { ... })`. Here, I used `live` to assign the listener also to *future* matches of the `.duplicate` selector.

Comment: Thanks David for your advice. Your suggestions did ultimately fix the problem, and now that I've had more time to work with jQuery, I realize how silly my code looks. Though it isn't specific to my code above, I did figure out that Chrome (and Safari) handle borders slightly different than IE, causing different input types to appear offset by a pixel or two (because different input types have different borders by default, depending on the browser). So explicitly defining all inputs (text, select, etc..) to have a single border style fixed the issue in that case.

Comment: I'm glad you worked it out :)